# Looking for an example for opening a file from a dropbox folder on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, dropbox

Using MonoTouch. Can this be done without OAuth since I have dropbox installed on my iPhone? Ideally I'd like to login to Dropbox with u/p the open a file from a path.

Thanks!